# How to stop Intellij from suggesting Promise import from jQuery

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, interface

Intellij is suggesting I import `Promise` from jQuery even though it's *not* undefined and my typescript configuration has `lib: ["es2015"]` (meaning typescript is aware that Promise is defined in the standard library).

It has type completions and everything. It's not red, the editor is fully aware of what `Promise` is, it just wants to import jQuery's definition for some unknown reason.

Pressing escape makes it disappear until I perform literally any other action.

It suggests it whether I use `Promise` as a value or a type.

It prevents the import suggestion behavior for things I really do want to import lower down in the file. And it slows everything down in my editor.

Ideally I could find a way for it to only suggest imports for variables that are undefined. Is that an option somewhere? I don't want to disable it completely.

[image]

**Update** Turning off inspections completely doesn't change the behavior. (Other information was also added above).

Comment: what IDEA version do you work with? Similar issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25869) was fixed in 2017.1...

Comment: @lena Looks like the same issue. My version is `2017.3`. So possibly reintroduced? Or different issue?

Comment: likely different; ctrl+click on `Promise` - what declaration are you taken to?

Comment: @lena I get 4 options, all of them are definition files within Typescript's `node_modules/lib/` directory, presumably because I'm including `lib: ["es2015"]` inside of my `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: so you have 4 libraries with different promise definitions. If any of them defines promise as external module that requires importing, prompts to import are expected:( You can suppress it by adding `// noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction` above the Promise call

Comment: @lena Unfortunately none of them defines Promise as an external module, and neither does the comment suppress the behavior. I even turned off all inspections and it persists. It doesn't appear to be a matter of inspections. `Promise` is defined, has type completions and the rest, it just has an annoying pop up above it.

Answer (score 0):

In Webstorm 2021.2 (and I imagine other intellij IDEs) there is now a context action to fix this:

1. Right click on `Promise`
2. Choose `Show Context Actions`
3. Choose `Enable library 'es2015.promise' in tsconfig.json`

Note that just hitting ALT+Enter will likely just do the import, so you need to right click to the the context actions menu.

To do it manually add '`es2105.promise` to the lib section of your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib" : [
      "es2015.promise",
    ],
  }
}
```